# Need to create a self deleting EXE

Tags: windows

I'm new to programming.
I need to write a Windows executable app, that deletes itself when the task is finished.

Any help?

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 
Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
As it stands your question would also be closed on [SO].

Comment: Sounds fishy...

Answer (score 1):

Call this VBScript file from your program

```
Wscript.Sleep 15000 'wait program finish running
Dim fso, MyFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.GetFile("your .exe file which call this vbs file")
MyFile.Delete


Dim objFSO    'Create a File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.DeleteFile WScript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: Tested, works.  I thought the deleting-self might cause an issue of the script file being in use, but had no permissions-issues/conflicts in Win7-64bit.  Personally, I would put an apostrophe at the start of the first line (disabling it).  Fortunately, the effect of that line, which I considered undesirable, was suitably commented so it did not prevent me from upvoting the answer.